# Change the returned field based on another table value in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, dynamic

I have a table called `Measures` which contains result values for a code in different fields depending on the PracticeID.  For example:

```
PracticeID Code Value1 Value2
---------- ---- ------ ------
1          CX   H      null
2          CX   null   L
```

So for PracticeID = 1 the result is in the field Value1 and for PracticeID = 2 the result is in field Value2 for the same code.

If I then create a translation table `Measure_Translate` which stores which field is to be used for a particular code at a particulare PracticeID. For example:

```
PracticeID Code ColumnName
---------- ---- ----------
1          CX   Value1
2          CX   Value2
```

Is there any way I can use the Measure_Translate table to dynamically determine which field needs to used to return the value for the measure (CX in this case)?

For example:

```
select m.PracticeID, m.Code,
--then dynamically get which Value field based on what is in the ColumnName
--field in Measure_Translate
from Measure as m
join Measure_Translate as t on t.PracticeID = m.PracticeID and t.Code = m.Code
```

If you can't change the actual tsql dynamically does anyone know any work around for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how artificial your example data is, but for this specific data no translation table is needed. The [coalesce()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) function can return the first value different from `null`.

**Sample data**

```
create table Measures
(
  PracticeId int,
  Code nvarchar(2),
  Value1 nvarchar(1),
  Value2 nvarchar(1)
);

insert into Measures (PracticeId, Code, Value1, Value2) values
(1,'CX','H',Null),
(2,'CX',Null,'L');
```

**Solution**

```
select m.PracticeId,
       m.Code,
       coalesce(m.Value1, m.Value2) as Value
from Measures m;
```

**Result**

```
PracticeId Code Value
---------- ---- -----
1          CX   H
2          CX   L
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1da755a91d368e1ec4de4cc522e2b48f)

---

If the sample data was oversimplified and you *really* need the tranlation, then you could use a [case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) expression.

**Sample data extension**

```
insert into Measures (PracticeId, Code, Value1, Value2) values
(3,'CX','H','L');

create table Measure_Translations
(
  PracticeId int,
  Code nvarchar(2),
  ColName nvarchar(20)
);

insert into Measure_Translations (PracticeId, Code, ColName) values
(1,'CX','Value1'),
(2,'CX','Value2'),
(3,'CX','Value2');
```

**Solution**

Contains both the `coalesce()` and the `case` approach to highlight the difference.

```
select m.PracticeId,
       m.Code,
       coalesce(m.Value1, m.Value2) as Value_coalesce,
       case mt.ColName
         when 'Value1' then m.Value1
         when 'Value2' then m.Value2
       end as Value_translation
from Measures m
join Measure_Translations mt
  on  mt.PracticeId = m.PracticeId
  and mt.Code = m.Code;
```

**Result**

```
PracticeId Code Value_coalesce Value_translation
---------- ---- -------------- -----------------
1          CX   H              H
2          CX   L              L
3          CX   H              L                 --> difference
```

[Extended fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e3bb344a784a7e5c0fca80ad5c37e8a2)